# spark jdbc api is giving error while accessing hive table with Map data type column

Tags: apache-spark, hive, data-migration, spark-jdbc

I have a hive table `tableA` with the following format:

```
> desc tableA;
+--------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--+
|         col_name         |       data_type       |        comment        |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--+
| statementid              | string                |                       |
| batchid                  | string                |                       |
| requestparam             | map<string,string>    |                       |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--+
```

I tried to load database with the following code:

```scala
val tempdf= spark.read.format("jdbc")
  .option("driver", "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")
  .option("url", "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/tempdb")
  .option("user","user1")
  .option("password","password1")
  .option("query","select statementid, batchid, requestparam from tempdb.tableA")
  .load()
```

And my second attempt:

```scala
val tempdf = spark.read.format("jdbc")
  .option("driver", "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")
  .option("url", "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/tempdb")
  .option("user","user1")
  .option("password","password1")
  .option("dbtable","tempdb.tableA")
  .load()
```

But `map<string,string>` column is causing an issue while loading source hive table into spark dataset.

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported type
> JAVA_OBJECT   at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.getCatalystType(JdbcUtils.scala:247)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$getSchema$1(JdbcUtils.scala:312)
> at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)     at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.getSchema(JdbcUtils.scala:312)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:63)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:226)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:354)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:326)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:308)
> at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)     at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:308)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:226)

Comment: Can you share the code too ?

Comment: @koiralo I tried with both options of dbtable and query as well. 
val tempdf= spark.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver").option("url", "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/tempdb").option("user","user1").option("password","password1").option("query","select statementid, batchid, requestparam from tempdb.tableA").load();

val tempdf= spark.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver").option("url", "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/tempdb").option("user","user1").option("password","password1").option("dbtable","tempdb.tableA").load();